# Adaptative banner height on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I have an app and I triyng to implement adaptative banner on a game screen. To do so, I need to know the height of the banner to reserve that space. But the method getHeight never return the true value of the banner, even after the banner is shown. How can I get that number on each device? I know that the banner height is never bigger than 15% of the screen height but on some devices is a lot lesser than that, so I end up with a lot of empty space on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to the native android code ? I mean can you bridge between Unity's **#C** code and Android's **Java/Kotlin** code, is yes, then you can use the function provided by the Admob itself.

Check out this Kotlin snippet I usually roll with:

```
val Activity.bannerAdSize: AdSize
    get() {
        val adWidthPixels = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            val windowMetrics = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
            val bounds = windowMetrics.bounds
            bounds.width().toFloat()
        } else {
            val outMetrics: DisplayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
            outMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat()
        }
        val density = resources.displayMetrics.density
        val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()
        return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth)
    }
```

It sets the **banner adSize** and has the parent container of the banner set to wrap content. Not certain about how this will integrate with Unity, but you might want to experiment with it. Hope this helps!

Comment: How could I get those codes on java/cotlin? I'm not sure about what you are reffering to

Comment: Can you show the code of how do you load the Banner in Unity? If I could understand that I might be able to help you.